# How to retry a apollo-client query when it fails?

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, server-side-rendering, apollo-client

In nextjs server layer (SSR), I have a query that sometimes fail on first try because the backend isn't ready.

```
 const PREVIEW = {
    query: MY_PREVIEW_QUERY,
    variables: { id, since },
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    context: {
      headers: {
        cookie,
      },
    },
  };
const { data, errors } = await apiApolloFetch(
    isPreviewRequest ? PREVIEW : STANDARD
  );


  if (errors) console.warn(errors);
```

The error only happens when it's a previewRequest. I would like to retry the fetch using ApolloClient. I looked at [polling](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#polling) but that does not help me because I only want to poll or retry when there is an error. I also looked [RetryLink](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-retry/) and it appears to be the answer but I cannot figure out how to use it.

I was able to get something working like the below snippet but I am still looking for an "Apollo" way to do the same thing.

```js
  const fetchPreview = async () => {
    let resp = await apiApolloFetch(PREVIEW);
    if (resp.data.preview == null) {
      await delay(2000);
      resp = await apiApolloFetch(PREVIEW);
    }
    return resp;
  };

  const { data, errors } = isPreviewRequest
    ? await fetchPreview()
    : await apiApolloFetch(STANDARD);
```

Comment: What about [refetch](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#refetching)?

Comment: @MichelFloyd apologies, this is happening on the server side as SSR in nextJs. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Apollo's [RetryLink](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-retry/) seems to be the blessed solution. To use it, you have to create a link that also includes the defaults. If you don't specify a link, I believe Apollo uses an [HttpLink](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http/) and passes `uri`, `headers`, etc from the `ApolloClient` constructor.

So this should work:

```
import { ApolloClient, from, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { RetryLink } from '@apollo/client/link/retry';

const link = from([
  new RetryLink(),
  new HttpLink({
    uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
    headers: {
      Authorization: Auth.getAuthHeader() ?? '',
    },
  }),
]);

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  // cache,
  // name,
  // etc,
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to only use RetryLink for certain useMutation calls?